# How could PC-Lint work with an interrupt?

Tags: c, xc8, pc-lint

I have the following code snippet for a PIC controller:

```
void __interrupt() ISR(void
{
    // do some stuff
}
```

when I use PC-Lint I always get the error message:

> Error 10: Expecting identifier or other declarator

What can I do to handle the interrupt in PC-Lint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a dummy preprocessor macro by using the option `-d__interrupt()=`